# How to replace successive null values of a particular column in a pandas with the top value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Suppose I have a data frame like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'first_column':  ['A', 'null', 'null', 'B', 'null', 'null', 'null' ],
        'second_column': [1, 3, 5, 32, 32, 12, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

I want to produce this

```
data = {'first_column':  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B' ],
        'second_column': [1, 3, 5, 32, 32, 12, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

how do I do it? I am newbie, I know replace.na, but it's not exactly straight forward I can apply here.

Answer (score 2):

Mask the 'null' as null/nan vaues, then forward fill with `ffill`:

```
df['first_column'] = df['first_column'].mask(df['first_column'] == 'null').ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values are actually na as opposed to the string 'null' then Pandas has a `.fillna()` function you can use. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna).

```
df['first_column'] = df['first_column'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `'null'` string by `NaN` and then use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna):

```
df['first_column'] = df['first_column'].replace('null', pd.NA).fillna(method='ffill')
# But if there are actually null values instead of 'null' then use:
# df['first_column'] = df['first_column'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
  first_column  second_column
0            A              1
1            A              3
2            A              5
3            B             32
4            B             32
5            B             12
6            B             51
```